# Register custom file extension for asp.net mvc5 view engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I register custom file extension for ASP.NET MVC view engine? In default ASP.NET MVC using file extensions: cshtml, vbhtml, aspx and I want to add my own.

I found some solutions, but there are out of date - doesn't work in nowadays or there are uncomplete - some step(s) is(are) missing for reproduce...

Comment: What do you want to register, and why?

Comment: css and js, I'm generating dynamiic css files and javascripts on fly.

Comment: OK, not sure of your exact requirements but let's say you want `.myext` to function as html. Could you register your extension's mime in the web.config as `text/html`, create the file with your html in it using that extension?

Comment: how can I register extension's mime in web.config? but I think you misunderstand - I need to register `.myext` to view engine - Razor. Razor is able consume only cshtml, vbhtml and aspx in default.

Comment: ah apologies - the mime type probably won't do the trick then. i've added the code below (just in case it helps in any way)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to register a new mime type in the web.config (edit: seeing your comment this may not do the trick but you asked so here's the details for future reference):

```
...
   <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".myext" mimeType="text/html" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```